# Only incoming audio recording in PJSIP

Tags: iphone, voip, pjsip

Right now i'm able to record my own voice or say outgoing (via mic) in pjsip, but i need to record just only incoming audio which is transmitted via speaker. Here is my code of recording outgoing voice in .wav format.
Please help me to done this task. Thanks in Adv.

```
-(int)startRecordAudio 
{
    pj_caching_pool cp;
    pjmedia_endpt *med_endpt;
    pj_pool_t *pool;
    pjmedia_port *file_port;
    pjmedia_snd_port *snd_port;
    char tmp[10];

    pj_status_t status;

    /* Must init PJLIB first: */
    status = pj_init();
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);

    /* Must create a pool factory before we can allocate any memory. */
    pj_caching_pool_init(&cp, &pj_pool_factory_default_policy, 0);
    status = pjmedia_endpt_create(&cp.factory, NULL, 1, &med_endpt);
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);

    /* Create memory pool for our file player */
    pool = pj_pool_create(&cp.factory,    /* pool factory       */
                          "app",          /* pool name.     */
                          4000,           /* init size      */
                          4000,           /* increment size     */
                          NULL            /* callback on error    */
                          );

    /* Create WAVE file writer port. */
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.wav"];

    status = pjmedia_wav_writer_port_create(pool,
                                            [foofile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                            CLOCK_RATE,
                                            NCHANNELS,
                                            SAMPLES_PER_FRAME,
                                            BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
                                            0, 0,
                                            &file_port);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to write file");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Create sound player port. */
    status = pjmedia_snd_port_create_rec(pool,       /* pool         */
                                         -1,         /* use default dev.        */
                                         PJMEDIA_PIA_SRATE(&file_port->info),/* clock rate.     */
                                         PJMEDIA_PIA_CCNT(&file_port->info),/* # of channels.       */
                                         PJMEDIA_PIA_SPF(&file_port->info), /* samples per frame.   */
                                         PJMEDIA_PIA_BITS(&file_port->info),/* bits per sample.     */
                                         0,      /* options      */
                                         &snd_port       /* returned port       */
                                         );

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
      //  app_perror(THIS_FILE, "Unable to open sound device", status);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Connect file port to the sound player.
     * Stream playing will commence immediately.
     */

    status = pjmedia_snd_port_connect( snd_port, file_port);
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);

    /* Sleep to allow log messages to flush */
    pj_thread_sleep(10);

    if (fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), stdin) == NULL) {
        puts("EOF while reading stdin, will quit now..");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution, I am stuck with the same issue. @Sudesh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do much.
In call media state check call active and connect following is in Java but function call are completely identical.

```
if (call_media_status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
                call_media_status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD) {
    int callConfSlot = call_info.getConf_slot();
    int status = pjsua.pjsua_recorder_create(pjsua.pj_str_copy("/storage/sdcard0/test.wav"), 0, null, 0, 0, ids);
    if (status != pjsuaConstants.PJ_SUCCESS) {
        App.logd("NOT SUCCESSFULL IN RECORDING=" + status);    
    } else {
        App.logd("Scccuessfull in recording");
        int recordPort = pjsua.pjsua_recorder_get_conf_port(ids[0]);
        pjsua.conf_connect(callConfSlot, recordPort);
        pjsua.conf_connect(0, recordPort);//this line includes microphone
    }}
```